# Replacing switch for pool spa

Tags: wiring, switch, 240v

The switch that controls our pool spa is currently located on the side of the house, behind our AC unit.  It's a very awkward, hard to reach location, so I'm currently looking into replacing it with a switch that can be remote controlled.

Given that the spa pump is wired for 240 volts, originally I was looking at a product similar to this:  [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00YTCZZF0?psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00YTCZZF0)

However, upon further reflection, the current switch looks to be a standard toggle switch, like I'd find on any light fixture.

My question is, is plan A overkill?  Is it safe to just replace the current switch with a different one in the same box? That would save me having to run alot of new wiring and conduit, and screw another box onto the side of the house.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Are you saying that if you don't go wireless you intend to run conduit/wire to a new (more accessible) location? To *"just replace the current switch with a different one in the same box"* should be fine, but I don't see what benefit you get from this.

Comment: Either way I'm going wireless, but the thing I'm not sure about is if I need the one linked above (since it's rated for 240V) or something like this that will fit in the existing switch box (https://www.amazon.com/GoControl-Z-Wave-Isolated-Contact-Fixture/dp/B00ER6MH22/ref=sr_1_33?s=hi&ie=UTF8&qid=1492440464&sr=1-33&keywords=zwave+switch)

Comment: ^For example, not necessarily the final product.

Comment: Your switch is a 2 pole or double pole switch (note 4 wires instead of 2 like a normal light switch). It switches two 120v legs which provide the pump with 240v.  It's a toggle style switch similar to a regular light switch, but double pole instead of single.   Another problem you have is that it doesn't appear that there is a neutral in that box, which you will need for the z-wave switch you linked.

Comment: I see. So l need to get a double pole z wave switch (If that's a thing), or 2 separate switches in parallel controlled together, correct?  I'm aware of the missing neutral, that's something I can add.

Comment: The product you linked to in the OP would work.  Here's the [wiring diagram](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DssJH.png) from the manufacturer's instructions.

Comment: You can't use "2 separate switches in parallel".  You need the product you linked.   I looked (rather briefly tho) to see if there was double pole z-wave switch that fit your single gang weatherproof box, but didn't see one.

Comment: @IanJacobs be careful adding the neutral - as there is a possibility that you can inadvertently provide a path for current flow and get a nice little shock from that pool.